# How to delete the rocksdb(flink state) file before flink jobmanager is deleted?

Tags: apache-flink, rocksdb

I want to remove all the rocksdb files before/after flink job cluster has been removed. We deployed the flink jobs on K8s. we store state on rocksdb for each job cluster. and the rocksdb which store the state will not be deleted when the job cluster is stopped. Any idea on it?

Comment: What filesystem are you using for the rocksdb files -- where are they?

Comment: we are using pvc which is mounted from pod?

Comment: If you haven‘t configured the checkpoints to be retained, they normally should be deleted, so check your config file first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no requirement for durable storage for RocksDB. You could simply use ephemeral local storage, rather than a PVC. Flink relies on the checkpoints for recovery, and doesn't need the local RocksDB instance to survive.

On other hand, if you want to use local recovery, then you'll need to use persistent local storage.